# Unity3d MultiTouch in Editor with Touch Screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building an application in unity on my laptop which has a touch screen.
I'm trying to get zoom to working on the camera.

I wrote a script to handle multi-touch

```
if (Input.touchCount == 2)
{
    var touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0);
    var touch1 = Input.GetTouch(1);

    var prevTouch0Pos = touch0.position - touch0.deltaPosition;
    var prevTouch1Pos = touch1.position - touch1.deltaPosition;

    var prevTouchMag = (prevTouch0Pos - prevTouch1Pos).magnitude;
    var touchMag = (touch0.position - touch1.position).magnitude;

    var deltaMag = prevTouchMag - touchMag;

    if(deltaMag > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Zoom in");
    }
    else if (deltaMag < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Zoom Out");
    }
}
```

When I'm debugging in the Unity Editor It never registers that I have two touches.   I have a touch screen laptop, is there a way I can setup the project so it will register those touches, or is there a way that I can use the mouse pad to simulate the touch screen?

Comment: Does the laptop-screen support multitouch? Which model is the laptop?

Comment: Yeah the laptop supports multi touch Lenovo ideapad y700 touch

Answer (score 0):

[Touch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch.html) does not listen to desktop OS Input. This only applies to Android, iOS and windows mobile.

Because not everyone has a touch screen pc, unity doesn't even consider putting time in something like this. You could write your own input system though. Take a look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.BaseInputModule.html)